# Restore single page of a database - syntax error

Tags: sql-server-2000

I'm trying to run this query

```
RESTORE DATABASE dbname
PAGE = '1:442'
FROM DISK = 'C:\dbname.bak'
WITH NORECOVERY
```

but getting the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'PAGE'.
```

Can you help me with this? I've found information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175168.aspx) and [here](http://www.sql-server-pro.com/dbcc-checkdb.html), and can't figure out there is the problem.

Comment: You are using SQL Server 2000, and that document is for SQL Server 2008.  This feature probably doesn't exist in the 2000 version.

Comment: @cdhowie Are there any other options to restore (maybe only one table)?

Comment: I don't know, I am not a SQL Server user.  I just noticed that the document was for a newer version, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page level restore isn't supported in SQL 2000. You will need to do a repair with data loss, restore the database with another name, then copy over the missing rows.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you restore the database as a different database, then copy the table over?

Comment: Because there are consistency error, and no operations with table are commited.

Comment: And you don't have a valid backup?

Comment: Why do think what? Did you read this line: `'C:\dbname.bak'`? It is a valid backup. I'm trying to know - is there any way to restore just one page from backup, and you just say - do the full backup.

Comment: I was just trying to suggest a workaround (the same workaround in the answer you accepted).